# elapsed_time_delta in dba_hist_sqlstats is not actual query run time?

Tags: oracle

I've been trying to explore `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` table. Encountered ambiguity with a column (lot more in fact) `ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA`. I ran a simple delete query and noted the time taken. But when I query the `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` and look at the `ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA` column (I know the units are ms) is showing different time than what I've captured manually. What all comes under `ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA` in `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` table ? Any explanation with example is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you mean `ELAPSED_TIME` columns.  There is no `EXECUTION_TIME` column in `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT`).

The `elapsed_time_delta` is the difference between the `elapsed_time_total` of the prior snap vs the current snap.

The `elapsed_time_total` is the total time spent executing that query since it was brought into the library cache.  That will not necessarily equal the "wall-clock" time of any single execution of that query, except possibly for the very 1st execution of the query by the 1st user -- and that only if you grabbed the `snap_id` after that 1st execution and before any subsequent executions.

That's hard to do and not always possible.  Generally speaking, you cannot use `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` to tell how long Oracle spent running a particular execution of a particular query.

What you **can** tell is how long Oracle spent running that query *on average* -- by finding the latest `snap_id` of interest and dividing `elapsed_time_total` by `nullif(executions_total,0)`.

Comment: I understand `elapsed_time_total` is cumulative of the `elapsed_time_delta` each `snap_id` has in it from the time the query loaded in library cache. I'm thankful to you if you can also explain what `elapsed_time_delta` deals with ? And also what is right place to look at how long an Oracle query has spent in past ?

Comment: You have it backwards, implying that `elapsed_time_delta` is the fundamental data and `elapsed_time_total` is a summation of that.  It's the other way.  Every time AWR collects data, it gets the current value of `elapsed_time_total` from the library cache.  It then computes `elapsed_time_delta` as the difference between this snap's `elapsed_time_total` and the last.  There is no way to know how long an Oracle query has run, except _on average_, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. May I ask if you could suggest any reference where I can find purpose of each of the columns in `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT table ? Not sure if I can post this comment here.

Comment: Yes, there is a reference.  It's actually called "Oracle Database Reference".  Here is the link to the section there on `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F5A246E0-C04A-406C-9E10-AC26E7742F06.htm#REFRN23447